# How to iterate over an arbitrary amount of lists as if using nested for loops?

Tags: python, algorithm

Assume I have the following lists, How to implement this:

LIST1    LIST2    LIST3

1        1        1

2        2        2

3        3        3

.        .        .

.        .        .

I want the behavior of iteration as follows:

1,1,1

1,1,2

1,1,3

1,2,1

1,2,2

1,2,3

1,3,1

1,3,2

1,3,3

2,1,1

.

.

.

This is a demonstration of what would happen for three lists, but in my actual use case I don't know the number of lists in advance.

Comment: Pick a language, please. Java or python?

Comment: Just use nested loops

Comment: @Aran-Fey any language is good to go, I want to learn how it is done in both languages

Comment: @MitchelPaulin can u plz show me how?

Comment: We got a python answer, so I'm removing the java tag.

Comment: `itertools.combinatons`

Comment: @NChauhan how about when we don't know the number of lists in advance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> how about when we don't know the number of lists in advance?

You can use `itertools.product` in this case, assuming you have a container `lists` holding your arbitrary number of lists.

Demo:

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> 
>>> lists = [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
>>> for value in product(*lists):
...     print(value)
... 
(1, 1, 1)
(1, 1, 2)
(1, 1, 3)
(1, 2, 1)
(1, 2, 2)
(1, 2, 3)
(1, 3, 1)
(1, 3, 2)
(1, 3, 3)
(2, 1, 1)
(2, 1, 2)
(2, 1, 3)
(2, 2, 1)
(2, 2, 2)
(2, 2, 3)
(2, 3, 1)
(2, 3, 2)
(2, 3, 3)
(3, 1, 1)
(3, 1, 2)
(3, 1, 3)
(3, 2, 1)
(3, 2, 2)
(3, 2, 3)
(3, 3, 1)
(3, 3, 2)
(3, 3, 3)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's simple iteration of loops.
In python you could go ahead and use 3 loops:

```
    for a in list1:
        for b in list2:
             for c in list3:
                  print(a,b,c)
```

Comment: how about when we don't know the number of lists in advance?

Comment: So assuming you'd have a database of lists, (since it's a physical entity through which data must be loaded), get the length of the number of columns, put that inside a list(youd have a list of lists) , iterate through the list decrementing it by 1 each time.